# How to generate wrapper code for existing contract with web3j?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I have a contract which I have compiled into the .bin and .abi files. However, generating the wrapper code for the contract like so:

```
web3j solidity generate -b ./Creation.bin -a ./Creation.abi -o ../../../java/ -p com.humboi.smart.contract
```

I get the following:

```
Unknown options: '-b', './Creation.bin', '-a', './Creation.abi', '-o', '../../../java/', '-p', 'com.humboi.smart.contract'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch `generate` and `solidity`. Then, there are three required arguments `--abiFile`, `--outputDir` and `--package`.

This gives:

```
web3j generate solidity --abiFile abi.json  --outputDir foo --package foo.bar
```